# MVC 3 FancyBox and IE data images not displaying properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fancybox

I convert on the fly an image to the `base64` string and I put it into the `src` attribute. To preview this image I use the `FancyBox` plugin (v1.3.4). In Firefox it works fine, but in the IE, if I click on the image, the result image is not being rendered properly. Why ?

Before click

[image]

After click

[image]

I've downloaded the v2.0.4 but it freezes the browser.

I've changed the plugin to the `LighBox` but the problem remained, so I suppose it' something wrong with the IE.

[image]

Comment: Is that a new tricky way to upload porn on websites without getting caught? :-D

Comment: Check that you are using a correct `DOCTYPE`. If that doesn't help, show a link with the sample of the issue (if we cannot help, at least we can see the rest of the pictures  ;)

Comment: Also you could try adding the API option `'type':'image'` to your fancybox custom script